# This one line of code has the expected ; before and unary minus errors for xcode iphone. It just one line! Ahhh!

Tags: iphone, xcode, urbanairship.com

Alright. So I asked a question here  but I feared that I anwsered it myself and closed the dicussion. No Idea if I did that. That question is available here; [Is it me or xcode... Somethings wrong with my braces and it just causes errors! Please help! iPhone SDK + Urban Push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411650/is-it-me-or-xcode-somethings-wrong-with-my-braces-and-it-just-causes-errors-p)

let me go ahead with my code that gives the expected ; and unary minus (which goes away if -(VOID) is removed but then that causes another error)

its here  if you need the full code its at the earlier link

```
  //Register for notifications;
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)]; 
  ;

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {  
 //ERROR HERE Wrong type argument to unary minus and semi colon b4
```

And I cant close the method after Register because then the lower references of  DeviceToken have no organized structure

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it me or xcode... Somethings wrong with my braces and it just causes errors! Please help! iPhone SDK + Urban Push](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411650/is-it-me-or-xcode-somethings-wrong-with-my-braces-and-it-just-causes-errors-p)

Comment: If you need to update the previous question, don't ask a new one, just edit the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand. I think the answer in your previous question is correct. Just close the method with a closing bracket } . What do you mean by "lower references of DeviceToken". I don't get it

Comment: Okay See the code that goes.... it says Request for deviceToken is something not a structure or union 
then _deviceToken undeclared first use 
and repeat with application undeclared etc

Comment: self.deviceToken = [[[[_deviceToken description] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""]
        stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]
       stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
  
  NSLog(@"Device Token: %@", self.deviceToken);

Comment: Where is your self.deviceToken, where is the property and synthesize of it? Did you declare them?

Comment: I even don't see any @synthesize deviceToken, that explains me anything about why XCode doesn't see your self.deviceToken

Comment: Look for something like window and viewController in the .h file and then try to do the same. @synthesize window; @synthesize viewController;

Comment: I know that. But I still get the errors. Where do I put the properties... in the properties nonatomic but what do I tag them as
Prop (nonatomic) ?????? DeviceToken

Comment: like this 
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData deviceToken *deviceToken;
ahh. Im stuck on such a simple issue.

Comment: You just need this.
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData *deviceToken

And don't forget @synthesize

Comment: No Declaration of deviceToken found 
i added syth deviceTocken and the property

Comment: I got it! 

In your header file:
NSString *deviceToken;
…..
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *deviceToken;


Can you explain why I am getting more errors like ASIHTTP undeclared 
expected ( before ASHTTP...

Comment: Me Neither. I just fail at declarations and need to hit the books again!